# Updating multiple HTML elements based on a JSON response from an API

Tags: javascript

```
    id: "1"
email: "TEST@TREST.COM"
selection1: "2"
race1: "1"
selection2: "4"
race2: "1"
selection3: "3"
race3: "0"
selection4: "2"
race4: "0"
selection5: "1"
race5: "0"
selection6: "1"
race6: "0"
selection7: "1"
race7: "0"
```

This is 1 on the objects in the Json array. so if race1=1 the class .race1 innerhtml = the email.

if Json.race2 = 1 .class race2 = the email and so on. if the race(number) = 0 dont write it

```
        const app = (() => {


      let race1 = document.querySelector('.race1');
      let race2 = document.querySelector('.race2');
      let race3 = document.querySelector('.race3');
      let race4 = document.querySelector('.race4');
      let race5 = document.querySelector('.race5');
      let race6 = document.querySelector('.race6');




    let xt=[]
      const returnAll = () => {



 fetch('/php/index.php')
          .then((response) => {
            return response.json();
          })
          .then((myJson) => {
            for (var i = 0; i < myJson.length; i++) {

              if (myJson[i].race1 == 1) {race1.innerHTML += `<div>${myJson[i].email} </div>`}
              if (myJson[i].race2 == 1) {race2.innerHTML += `<div>${myJson[i].email} </div>`}
              if (myJson[i].race3 == 1) {race3.innerHTML += `<div>${myJson[i].email} </div>`}
              if (myJson[i].race4 == 1) {race4.innerHTML += `<div>${myJson[i].email} </div>`}
              if (myJson[i].race5 == 1) {race5.innerHTML += `<div>${myJson[i].email} </div>`}
              if (myJson[i].race6 == 1) {race6.innerHTML += `<div>${myJson[i].email} </div>`}
            }

          });





      }

      return {

        init: () => {

          returnAll();
        }


      }



    })();


    app.init();
```

All the information above is correct and works occordingly. I just need a better way to code this rather than multiple if statements, Switch would pretty much the same! Any suggestions? I find multple If statements are easy to read, however I've been told this is bad coding.
I've tried Object.key which works fine for the html part, the issue is comparing myJson.race1 =1, myJson.race2 = 1.
i've tried myJson[i].race[i] but that then returns [object,object].race0 (up to race5).

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! We need to know *what the code is intended to achieve*. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question, including a title that summarises the *purpose* of the code. We want to know **why** much more than **how**. The more you tell us about [what your code is for](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1226), the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.  The title needs an [edit] to simply [**state the task**](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2436), rather than your concerns about the code.

Comment: You'll need to show us what the JSON looks like you are working with.

Answer (score 1):

We can start by building an object containing our race elements rather than having 6 different objects

```js
const racePrefix = 'race';
const raceElements = {};
const numRaceElements = 6;

for (let i = 1; i <= numRaceElements; i++) {
    numRaceElements[racePrefix + i] = document.querySelector('.' + racePrefix + i);
}
```

then when we loop over the JSON we can check each key in turn:

```js
for (const jsonRow of myJson) {
    for (const fieldName in jsonRow) {
        if (raceElements[fieldName] instanceof HTMLElement && jsonRow[fieldName] == 1) {
            raceElements[fieldName].innerHTML += `<div>${jsonRow.email} </div>`;
        }
    }
}
```

Now if in future you ever need to change anything like adding new races, or changing the class name it's easy to do in a single place without breaking anything.